# Import "aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2_integrations" could not be resolved

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am trying to build a cdk stack to connect a lambda function to React static website through api Gateway.

```
from aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2_integrations import HttpLambdaIntegration

# ...
```

I got the code sample of the api gateway from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2/README.html#http-api).

I get the following message when importing `aws_apigatewayv2_integrations`:

```
Import "aws_cdk.aws_apigatewayv2_integrations" could not be resolved
```

I installed the package so I got a message error saying that the constructs package was downgraded from 10.3.0 to 3.4.344

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behavior is the source of the following dependency conflicts.

aws-cdk-lib 2.110.0 requires constructs<11.0.0,>=10.0.0, but you have constructs 3.4.344 which is incompatible.
```

By the way, I am using a virtual environment and installed the following packages:

```
aws-cdk-lib==2.110.0
constructs>=10.0.0,<11.0.0
```

So how to use `aws_apigatewayv2_integrations` directly from aws-cdk-lib without needing to install it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade `aws-cdk-lib` to the latest version in your `requirements.txt` file:

```
aws-cdk-lib==2.114.1
constructs>=10.0.0,<11.0.0
```

And then ensure you install them:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

The import should then work.